# Api gateway using data terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have a custom domain in api gateway which is not managed by terraform. The custom domain be cdn.qa1.example.com and API Gateway domain name associated with it ddd4qddddddda.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. I want to add a cname in route 53 for the domain cdn.qa1.example.com. How can get the api gateway domain name using terraform data block.

```
   data "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "example" {
  domain_name = "cdn.qa1.example.com"
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "talks" {
  #count   = var.TF_BT_ENV == "stage" || var.TF_BT_ENV == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = "xxxxxxx"
  name    = "cdn.qa1.example.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = data.aws_api_gateway_domain_name.example.target_domain_name
}
      
@Justines-MacBook-Pro terraform_code % terraform13.7 plan

Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_route53_record" "talks":
  11:   records = data.aws_api_gateway_domain_name.custom_domain.target_domain_name

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"target_domain_name".
```

but thats not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any error, warning?

Comment: Its not giving the ddd4qddddddda.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com as output. Or how can we get it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is clearly stating, and you can see clearly by looking at [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/api_gateway_domain_name), there is no attribute named `target_domain_name` on a `aws_api_gateway_domain_name` datasource.

Instead, you should probably be creating a Route53 `Alias` record using the `cloudfront_domain_name` and `cloudfront_zone_id` attributes of the datasource.